# Twitter Timeline DOM Manipulation - Negating Onclick Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, twitter, dom-events

I am creating a browser extension that modifies the Twitter timeline by adding some links to each tweet row in a user's Twitter timeline.

Generally whenever the tweet row is clicked, Twitter will pop out the right-hand panel with more information, except for when the user clicks links like Retweet, Reply, etc. I'm not sure what Twitter's JavaScript is applying to these links to prevent them from causing the panel to be opened, but I'd like to do something similar. I have tried inspecting the elements in Google Chrome, but the event handlers are not revealed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by stopping the event propagation. This prevented the event from propagating to the event handler for the container element.

With jQuery I was able to apply an onclick handler like so:

```
$("#elementId").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    // other actions
});
```

Comment: I would suggest that you look into the non-jQuery way to do this - unless you're already planning on using jQuery in your extension.  I wouldn't.  :)

Comment: @Chris: jQuery is used throughout the extension for several things. You're right that this case alone does not really warrant its use.

Comment: Be sure to accept your own answer, now that enough time has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

The event handlers are probably being added programmatically via script.  You could try to remove the event handlers (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener)), but it might be easier to clone the element in question, then hide the original. See [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) documentation for information.

Without any sample html, I can't really give you a good example, but here's a generic jsFiddle I threw together to demonstrate the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/sacCK/1/

Comment: I'm quite sure that their script is not adding an event handler to the DOM elements that I insert. It is more of a problem that wherever the user clicks on the tweet row will cause the panel to open (except for their links). I'd like to replicate the way their links function, such that they do not cause the panel to open when clicked. I think the event handler is on the outer container (containing all tweet text, etc.), so the event handler is probably being called but the handler on the link stops the panel from opening.